# In Gmail, how do you hide labels from the "Move To" dropdown menu?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

I have several labels in the "Move To" dropdown menu, and I'd like to keep the labels but hide some of them. Advice?

Answer (score 5):

You can't. That menu holds all of your labels. The only way to remove a label from that list is to remove the label altogether.

If you're having trouble with finding your more important labels amongst a long list, I suggest changing your label name to have some sort of non-numeric character in the front. I do that with a handful of my labels to make sure they're at the top of the list.

So instead of

```
Joe
```

I have

```
!Joe
```

Now my "Joe" label is at the top rather than halfway down the list.

Comment: Adding a "z" at the beginning of the labels you don't want to see should be even easier.

Comment: By the way, I used to use "~" to get things to go to the top, but GMail is inconsistent with that one.  In some views (the list on the side, and the "Labels" drop-down list) it comes *first*, and in others (the ordering of labels on individual conversations) it comes *last*.  That would be useful if you wanted something prominent in some places but not in others.

Comment: Being able to completely hide a label is an important feature. Google should implement this! This is the only way to keep old mail organized while still having an uncluttered drop-down list

Answer (score 2):

You can change the name of a label to make sure that it sorts at the top of the list, a number or and underscore works great.

You can't hide a label from the pull down list but you can make [other changes](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/118708?rd=1):

When looking at the list of labels under "Move to" or "Labels" You can used the manage labels command to hide a label from the sidebar list

> **Choose which labels appear in your list on the left**: In the "Show in
>   label list" column, click the "show" or "hide" link next to each label
>   to choose whether it will be shown in the left panel of your Gmail
>   pages. You can also set labels to appear only when they contain unread
>   messages (otherwise, they will be hidden).
>
> **Choose which labels appear on your messages**: In the "Show in message
>   list" column, you can choose whether you'll see each label displayed
>   next to its messages' subject lines. Click hide if you don't want to
>   see that label name when you look at the messages it contains.
>
> **Delete labels**: If you see a label that you don't want anymore, click
>   remove in the "Remove label" column. (You'll have to confirm that
>   you'd like to remove the label by clicking Delete.)

Answer (score 2):

And one more note, if you have a bunch of sub-categories, it will rename them all. So, if I have a category at the top like `apples` and then a bunch of subcategories like `apples\red`, `apples\yellow` and I add a `z` to them, it will add the `z` to all of the categories and move them all to the bottom which is handy as well.